# In an Cocoa, OSX Swift application, how to get names of the subviews

Tags: swift, macos, subviews

In our last OSX application, we needed getting subview names. Using following function we can check how many NSImageView in our given view but not the name (index numbers) of NSImageViews. Actually NSImageViews kept in an array and we need index number of NSImageViews.

```
// Returns how many NSImageViews we had in a given view.

func subViewCheck (viewName viewName: NSView) -> Int {

    var counter: Int = 0
    let views = viewName.subviews 

    for k in 0..<views.count {

    if views[k].description.containsString("NSImageView")  { 

        counter += 1

        }
    }

return counter

}
```

Comment: can be `viewWithTag` with the views

Comment: _let index = views[k].tag_ could be yes. I have to add tag when creating NSImageViews then.

Comment: then you get them by their tag name

Comment: That answers my question  if you write it as answer I will check it as answered by you.